# Download PDFs from URLs via loop

Tags: r, loops, pdf

I have a dataframe **df** containing a column **URL** from which I want to download the PDFs behind those URLs.

Here is the `dput()` for the df:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Cran", "Beginners", "Split"), Ticker = c("CAR", 
"BEG", "SPL"), URL = c("https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf", 
"https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf", 
"https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPlit/SPlit.pdf")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I want to download all PDFs from all links in the URL column and name them in the fashion of *Name_Ticker*, for example Cran_CRA for the first link.

For downloading one PDF I have been using the following code:

```
require(XML)
url <- ('https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf')
download.file(url, 'Cran_CRA.pdf', mode="wb")
```

How can I adapt this code to loop through the URL column and download all PDFs and name them according to the example above?

Additionally, how can I "skip" links for which the PDF-URL does not work/is a wrong URL?

EDIT: Here is the `head()` of my actual dataframe

```
Name                     Ticker URL                     
  <chr>                    <chr>  <chr>                   
1 Dash 2 Trade             D2T    https://dash2trade.com/assets/documents/Whitepaper.pdf
2 Calvaira                 RIA    https://whitepaper.calvaria.io/?utm_source=coincodex&utm_medium=referral
3 Flow                     FLOW   https://www.onflow.org/technical-paper?utm_source=coincodex&utm_medium=referral
4 Cosmos                   ATOM   https://cosmos.network/resources/whitepaper?utm_source=coincodex&utm_medium=referral
5 CUDOS Token              CUDOS  NA                      
6 P2P solutions foundation P2PS   https://www.p2psf.org//wp-content/uploads/2017/12/P2PS_Whitepaper_V1.1_English.pdf?utm_source=coincodex&utm_medium=referral
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to iterate over the length of the dataframe, and `download.file` there.

Use a `if` statement with `RCurl::url.exists` to check the validity of the urls.

```
library(RCurl)

df2 <- df %>% as.data.frame()

lapply(1:nrow(df2), \(x) {
  if (url.exists(df2[x, "URL"])) download.file(df2[x, "URL"], paste0(df2[x, "Name"], "_", df2[x, "Ticker"], ".pdf"), mode="wb")
  })
```

Comment: Works great on my test df but on my actual df I get the error ```Error in download.file(urls[x, 3], paste0(urls[x, 1], "_", urls[x, 2], :
invalid 'url' argument``` - any idea why?

Comment: @Soph2010 Is column 3 of your `urls` dataframe all valid links?

Comment: no, there could be some urls that are not valide. Any idea how to skip these?

Comment: @Soph2010 See if my updated code helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the adaption. Unfortunately it still does not work for my actual code even though the first url is definitely valid (https://dash2trade.com/assets/documents/Whitepaper.pdf). As output it gives NULL for every row.

Comment: @Soph2010 Can you share the `head` of your actual dataframe? I can run the code without trouble on my side (and yes I can download the PDF from your dash2trade.com). I suspect your urls are not stored in column 3 of your actual dataset, see my updated code again :)

Comment: sure, I added the ```head()``` in my orginal post as an edit!

Comment: @Soph2010 The problem is your dataframe is of `tibble`, where subsetting it would return `tibble`, where `url.exists` cannot recognise. Therefore you have to use `as.data.frame` to make it data.frame before using my codes :)